# How can I add an authenticated nuget feed to Teamcity globally?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, teamcity

I'm currently trying to add a Azure Devops artefact feed to Teamcity so I can pull dependencies built in Azure to our legacy Teamcity build server. I understand that I can use the Nuget Feed Credentials build feature to handle the authentication of this with an access token.

What I'm struggling with is that this build feature appears to need to be added to each build individually. Is there a way to handle this authentication centrally so I don't need to modify every build config where I want to use this feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution endded up being to create a build configuration template and use that to handle the auth.

1. [Create new build configuration template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/creating-and-editing-build-configurations.html#Creating+Build+Configuration+Template) on the root project
2. [Add Nuget feed credentials step to the build configuration template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/nuget-feed-credentials.html) (username can be anything, password should be a PAT which can read the feed)
3. [Apply the new build configuration template to the root project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-configuration-template.html#Defining+default+template+for+project)

The end result of this is all your projects will have the same nuget authentication config.